# Java.time (Java 8) support in Freemarker

Tags: java-8, freemarker

Does anybody know of any plans to support the new java.time api in FreeMarker? Or has anybody code laying around for supporting classes like ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime and Instant?

Its not hard to see how to implement these things myself, but it is actually a rather big task.

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume that you want format new date/time objects

1. Create custom method:

   ```
   public static class FormatDateTimeMethodModel 
           implements TemplateMethodModelEx {
       public Object exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {
           if (args.size() != 2) {
               throw new TemplateModelException("Wrong arguments");
           }
           TemporalAccessor time = (TemporalAccessor) ((StringModel) args.get(0)).getWrappedObject();
           DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(((SimpleScalar) args.get(1)).getAsString());
           return formatter.format(time);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put this method into template model:

   templateModel.put("formatDateTime", new FormatDateTimeMethodModel());
3. And invoke this method inside of template:

   ${formatDateTime(MY_DATE, 'HH:mm')}

Comment: @Autowired private FormatDateTimeMethodModel fdtmm;@ModelAttribute("formatDateTime")
    public FormatDateTimeMethodModel formatDateTime(Authentication authentication) {
        return fdtmm;
    } if you want to use it in freemarker templates

Answer (score 3):

Nobody deals with that right now (2.3.24), though it's known to be missing. It probably won't be trivial to do properly, unless degrading Java 8 date/time types to `java.util.Date`-s when they are returned by `TemplateDateModel` is acceptable.

BTW, I have added this to http://freemarker.org/contribute.html, so that it won't be forgotten.

Comment: Thnx for adding it. I think degrading to java.util.Date will be a huge step in the wrong direction. Comments in the source code argues that a lot of the date complexity is caused by the fact that java.util.Date doesn't have a good way of handling only timestamps, dates and so on. 

I'm working on a new set of TemplateModel's and a new ObjectWrapper that will support all the java.time objects and make sure they are formatted correctly. This is the only way to solve it at the moment I guess? I will post some more info about it when its ready. I guess we can open it up on github .

Comment: Just a minor mispelling in the contribute.html site. You wrote "Support for Java 8 data/time API-s". I guess you ment "Support for Java 8 date/time API-s" ;)

Comment: Thanks, typo fixed. As of how to solve this... certainly it starts with new DataModel interfaces. So those are new types in FTL, that it has to be able to convert to string according the configuration settings. Also the date/time built-ins may have to be able to handle these new types... So it's quite a work. (Also there will be some ugliness as FreeMarker has to run on Java 5.)

Comment: I have done some initial work on a small implementation tonight. If you have time I would love your comments : https://github.com/amedia/freemarker-java-8 . Maybe there is a better way? Or am I on the right track for now? Until we have a plan for the real implementation I mean.

Comment: You'll find some tests here : https://github.com/amedia/freemarker-java-8/blob/master/src/test/resources/no/api/freemarker/java8/time/datetime.feature . I will add more if you think this is the only/right way to go.

Comment: I'm not yet sure how could FreeMarker integrate with `java.time`. Never though of it. Your solution is not really integration (if we agree in that - it doesn't use date/time format config settings, can't compare dates, etc.), but then again, this is perhaps the best you can realistically do for now.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely not an integration. Its just a pragmatic attempt to find a solution on how to to use beans containing classes from the new API, which I need asap. I would be happy to discuss the integration with you sometime. I think what we first need to embrace is the fact that the new api is more complex in a good way. We do not longer have to "guess" the meaning of an object and pick out only the parts we need. The downside of course is that all users actually must understand the difference between for instance ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime and OffsetDateTime.

Comment: Just so that it's clear to anyone reading this, you can just use the Java API of `java.time` classes out-of-the-box, like with any the other classes out there which has no equivalent in FTL's type "system". Only of course you will certainly want a better string value than what `toString()` returns, and add some shortcuts for formatting.

Comment: Good point. I probably wasn't to clear about that. Feel free to use https://github.com/amedia/freemarker-java-8

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with java 8 java.time using the explanation here: https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/spring/java-8-datetime-freemarker/

I used this approach because DefaultObjectWrapper is deprecated.

I am using freemarker version 2.3.31

1. pom.xml - add the following dependency

   ```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>no.api.freemarker</groupId>
         <artifactId>freemarker-java8</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Java freemarker configuration setup

   ```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31);
    configuration.setObjectWrapper(new Java8ObjectWrapper(configuration.getIncompatibleImprovements()));
   ```
3. Template date formatting - format new dates the following way

   ```
    ${(person.dateOfBirth).format("dd.MM.yyyy")}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static class CustomObjectWrapper extends DefaultObjectWrapper {
    @Override
    public TemplateModel wrap(Object obj) throws TemplateModelException {
        if (obj instanceof LocalDateTime) {
            Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf((LocalDateTime) obj);
            return new SimpleDate(timestamp);
        }
        if (obj instanceof LocalDate) {
            Date date = Date.valueOf((LocalDate) obj);
            return new SimpleDate(date);
        }
        if (obj instanceof LocalTime) {
            Time time = Time.valueOf((LocalTime) obj);
            return new SimpleDate(time);
        }
        return super.wrap(obj);
    }
}


@Autowired
private freemarker.template.Configuration configuration;

configuration.setObjectWrapper(new CustomObjectWrapper());
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.