# How to get the day (ex: Monday) from a time Instant in FreeMarker

Tags: java, date, freemarker

So I got this **Instant** date in Java: "2018-05-19T22:00:00Z".

How can I get the day of the week? like monday..

I was trying this but it doesn't work:

```
${date?string["EEEE"]}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Freemarker does not work with Instant, so you would need to convert that to string in Java (something like "2018-05-19T22:00:00Z") and then convert the string doing the following:

```
<#setting locale="en_US">
${"2018-05-19T22:00:00Z"?datetime.iso?string["EEEE"]}
```

First convert the string to datetime in iso format, and then back again to string with the pattern of your choosing.

By changing the locale setting, you may get the day of the week in different languages.

I think that the best way to work in Freemarker is to always have strings or integers variables.

Answer (score 1):

`${date?string["EEEE"]}` works fine as long as `date` is a `java.util.Date` object.

You can test it in this way:

```
<#assign date = .now>
${date?string["EEEE"]}
```

I guess that it doesn't work because your `date` is a `String`, in this case you should parse it in Java (server-side) and expose a `java.util.Date` variable to the template.

Comment: No, it's not a string, it's an instant (as mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

At this point FreeMarker does not support Java 8 time, see the [contribute](https://freemarker.apache.org/contribute.html) page:

> ## What should I contribute?
>
> Usually, contributors come because they want to fix/improve a certain thing. But if you just want to help in general, here are some topics ...
>
> - Support for Java 8 date/time API-s (this is actually certainly a difficult one). Note that there's a 3rd party solution for this, https://github.com/amedia/freemarker-java-8, but it's not as seamless as a native solution could be.
> - ...

So you could check out the third party solution.

See also:

- [Java.time (Java 8) support in Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063276/java-time-java-8-support-in-freemarker)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use new Date Time API defined in Java 8.Using Date Time API you can fetch all data related to Date and Time easily.

Java 8 has defined a separate Enum for handling days of the week named – DayOfWeek (java.time.DayOfWeek)

java.time.DayOfWeek is an Enum which defines 7 constants representing the seven days of the week – MONDAY(int value=1), TUESDAY(2), WEDNESDAY(3)… till SUNDAY(7).

```
import java.time.*;

public class Java8Tester {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Java8Tester java8tester = new Java8Tester();
      java8tester.testLocalDateTime();
   }

   public void testLocalDateTime() {
      // Get the current date and time
      LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-05-19T22:00:00");
      System.out.println("Current DateTime: " + currentTime);


    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = currentTime.getDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(currentTime + " was a " + dayOfWeek);
   }
}
```

Comment: @sanjeev51 how can this be used in a FreeMarker template?