# Freemarker Error Expected hash?

Tags: java, date, freemarker

I want to transform a Instant time to Date but I'm getting this error:

freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash. newDate evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleDate

I'm doing this on Java:

```
Date newDate = new Date();
Instant instant =  Instant.now();

webContext.put("newDate",new Date());
webContext.put("instant",instant);
```

And I'm doing this on Freemarker:

```
[#assign dateFormated = newDate.getAsDate().from(instant.ofEpochSecond(data.time.seconds))/]
```

Thank you

Comment: you mean `Date newDate = Date.from(Instant.now());`

Comment: @YCF_L mm no, I do it for initialize the variable and in Freemarker can do newDate.getAsDate().from(instant.ofEpochSecond(data.time.seconds))

Comment: with my solution I think you need just `[#assign dateFormated = newDate/]` I'm not familiar with freemaker

Comment: @YCF_L I can't do that because on Freemarker im doing a for for each data and getting the dates so I cant pass each date on Java to freemarker, well I can, but that doesn't work for me

Comment: hmm sorry then i don't have any idea

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker templates don't in general expose Java API-s, or allow you to access Java classes by name. I mean, in some cases it does, but not in general like `newDate` has no subvariables (like `getAsDate`) in FreeMarker. There are utilities with which you can expose the static methods of classes, like:

```
TemplateHashModel staticModels
        = ((BeansWrapper) configuration.getObjectWrapper())
          .getStaticModels();
webContext.put("Date", staticModels.get("java.util.Date"));
webContext.put("Instant", staticModels.get("java.time.Instant"));
```

where `configuration` is your `freemarker.template.Configuration` singleton. Actually, you can add `Date` and `Instant` to that singleton with `Configuration.setSharedVariable`, once where you configure FreeMarker.

And then, you can write `Date.from(Instant.now())` into a template, because now there's a `Date` and and `Instant` variable, and you have specifically told FreeMarker to expose thier static methods.

Comment: I'm doing  this:  `configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_0);` but when I do `configuration.get...` It doesn't works, it doesn't autocomplete. Thank you!

Comment: Well it should... have you tried if it compiles? Anyway, it's suspicious if you create a `new` `Configuration`. You already have a singleton instance somewhere. Maybe you can autowire it or something.